# How do you change the DNS for a website hosted on an Azure Linux server VM?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, cmsmadesimple

I have a website running CMSMadeSimple on an Azure Linux VM. The current URL is `[website].cloudapp.net/cmsmadesimple`, but now that the site is complete I need to change the it to the client's URL `[website].com`.

I've done this in the past by simply remoting in to the server and changing the DNS records, but since the VM is Linux, I can't just remote it. I've looked around but have yet to find a solution.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just [create a CNAME or A record](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/). However, your application server must cooperate by redirecting the request to your new hostname to the existing application. It's likely a VirtualHost is already setup for this but if you get a 404 then you need to ["remote" in.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/)

Answer (score 0):

First update the config.php files for the new domain.

Second update your vhost files on your webserver to listen to the new domain.

Final update the DNS (usually it is where you registered the domain -- like godaddy.com, namecheap.com, etc) to point to the IP or alias given to you by Azure.